# Tish'a Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred nine?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words in the parsha with gematra 109:

כא,ל ויאמר--כי את-שבע כבשת, תקח מידי:  בעבור תהיה-לי **לעדה**, כי חפרתי את-הבאר הזאת.

יח,כב ויפנו משם האנשים, וילכו **סדמה**; ואברהם--עודנו עמד, לפני יהוה.

יט,לב לכה נשקה את-אבינו יין, ונשכבה עמו; ונחיה **מאבינו**, זרע

Answer (score 2):

109 were the [years](http://books.google.com/books?id=8RnWhJxpEP4C&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=%22109+years%22+binyamin&source=bl&ots=3qz4iHIHQb&sig=gc_yg8lw6waGeHLj0QidLuHU4TQ&hl=en&ei=ZZHATKaVMsWt8AbioYTCBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22109%20years%22%20binyamin&f=false) of Binyamin.